# Relations between tables in ASP.NET Web forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ef-code-first

i am working on a website, and i am using code first for creating database.
my video class :

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int VideoId { get; set; }

    [Required,DisplayName("Session Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required, DisplayName("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required, DisplayName("Video")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false),DisplayName("Sent Date")]
    public DateTime SentDate { get; set; }

    [Required, DisplayName("Keywords")]
    public string Keywords { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false), DisplayName("sLug")]
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false), DisplayName("Status")]
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [Required,DisplayName("Image")]
    public string Picture { get; set; }

    //[Required,DisplayName("Rate")]
    //public int Rate { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public VidUser User { get; set; }
```

so as you can see i have 2 properties : `Course` and `VidUser`
thees properties are my classes `VidUser` is my users class (using ASP.NET Identity `ApplicationUser` class in ASP.NET Identity).
VidUser :

```
public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Video> Videos { get; set; }
```

and Course class :

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public int SessionCount { get; set; }

    public VidUser Teacher { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Video> Videos { get; set; }
```

my question is how to relation between thees tables, you know every user (VidUser) can be teacher of courses and can every Course has one teacher and same as this for other classes that i wrote at top.
so some where i need to get video details but i got null reference error :

```
var db = new MyContext();
db.Videos.Where(v => v.Course.CourseId == 2).FirstOrDefault(); //This line returns null
```

or for getting user name :

```
var db = new MyContext();
db.Videos.Where(v => v.User.UserName == "Admin").FirstOrDefault(); //This line returns null
```

and my seed method is :

```
#region Roles
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<VidRole>(new RoleStore<VidRole>(context));
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
        {
            roleManager.Create(new VidRole("Admin","مدیر کل"));
        }
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Manager"))
        {
            roleManager.Create(new VidRole("Manager", "مدیر سایت"));
        }
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Writer"))
        {
            roleManager.Create(new VidRole("Writer", "نویسنده"));
        }
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("RegisteredUser"))
        {
            roleManager.Create(new VidRole("RegisteredUser","کاربر عضو"));
        }
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("VIP"))
        {
            roleManager.Create(new VidRole("VIP","کاربر ویژه"));
        }
        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("BannedUSers"))
        {
            roleManager.Create(new VidRole("BannedUSers","کاربر محروم"));
        }
        #endregion

        #region Users
        var usermanager = new UserManager<VidUser>(new UserStore<VidUser>(context));
        var user = new VidUser()
        {
            UserName = "Admin",
            Avatar = "/UserFiles/Admin/brands_01.jpg",
            Email = "MrSadin@Gmail.Com",
            FullName = "K. Sadin",
            Website = "http://Sadin.ir",
            Description = "..."
        };
        var user1 = new VidUser()
        {
            UserName = "User",
            Avatar = "/UserFiles/Admin/brands_02.jpg",
            Email = "MrSadin@Gmail.Com",
            FullName = "K. Sadin",
            Website = "http://Sadin.ir",
            Description = "..."
        };
        var user2 = new VidUser()
        {
            UserName = "Manager",
            Avatar = "/UserFiles/Admin/brands_03.jpg",
            Email = "MrSadin@Gmail.Com",
            FullName = "K. Sadin",
            Website = "http://Sadin.ir",
            Description = "..."
        };
        var userCreationResult = usermanager.Create(user, "kamisevenline");
        var userCreationResult2 = usermanager.Create(user1, "kamisevenline");
        var userCreationResult3 = usermanager.Create(user2, "kamisevenline");
        #endregion

        #region Add User To Role
        if (userCreationResult.Succeeded)
        {
            usermanager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
            usermanager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Manager");
            usermanager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Writer");
            usermanager.AddToRole(user.Id, "RegisteredUser");
            usermanager.AddToRole(user.Id, "VIP");
            usermanager.AddToRole(user1.Id, "Admin");
            usermanager.AddToRole(user2.Id, "Writer");
        }
        #endregion

        //Test Data:
        #region Testing Data, Should Remove in the future

        var course1 = new Course()
        {
            Title = "آموزش ام وی سی",
            Description = "در این دوره از ابتدا یک سیستم را با MVC طراحی میکنیم و در طی چلسات با نکات آشنا میشویم.",
            StartDate = DateTime.Now,
            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1),
            Teacher = user,
            SessionCount = 10
        };
        var course2 = new Course()
        {
            Title = "آموزش ASP.NET 5.5",
            Description = "در این دوره آموزش بنیادین ASP.NET 4.5 را شروع میکنیم و تا آخر دوره پروژه ای آماده خواهیم کرد.",
            StartDate = DateTime.Now,
            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
            Teacher = user,
            SessionCount = 10,
        };
        context.SaveChanges();
        context.Videos.AddOrUpdate(new Video()
        {
            Address = "/Videos/Admin/MVC/Vid01.mp4",
            Description = "در جلسه اول با این قسما ها آشنا می شویم. مدیریت،کاربران، و دیگر بخش ها",
            Keywords = "کلیدواژه,MVC,آموزش MVC",
            Picture = "/images/dummy/products/product-6.jpg",
            SentDate = DateTime.Now,
            Slug = "جلسه-اول-آموزش-mvc",
            Status = true,
            Title = "جلسه اول آموزش MVC",
            User = user,
            Course = course1
        }); context.Videos.AddOrUpdate(new Video()
        {
            Address = "/Videos/Admin/MVC/Vid01.mp4",
            Description = "در جلسه اول با این قسما ها آشنا می شویم. مدیریت،کاربران، و دیگر بخش ها",
            Keywords = "کلیدواژه,MVC,آموزش MVC",
            Picture = "/images/dummy/products/product-6.jpg",
            SentDate = DateTime.Now,
            Slug = "جلسه-اول-آموزش-mvc",
            Status = true,
            Title = "جلسه اول آموزش MVC",
            User = user,
            Course = course2
        }); context.Videos.AddOrUpdate(new Video()
        {
            Address = "/Videos/Admin/MVC/Vid01.mp4",
            Description = "در جلسه اول با این قسما ها آشنا می شویم. مدیریت،کاربران، و دیگر بخش ها",
            Keywords = "کلیدواژه,MVC,آموزش MVC",
            Picture = "/images/dummy/products/product-6.jpg",
            SentDate = DateTime.Now,
            Slug = "جلسه-اول-آموزش-mvc",
            Status = true,
            Title = "جلسه اول آموزش MVC",
            User = user,
            Course = course1
        }); context.Videos.AddOrUpdate(new Video()
        {
            Address = "/Videos/Admin/MVC/Vid01.mp4",
            Description = "در جلسه اول با این قسما ها آشنا می شویم. مدیریت،کاربران، و دیگر بخش ها",
            Keywords = "کلیدواژه,MVC,آموزش MVC",
            Picture = "/images/dummy/products/product-6.jpg",
            SentDate = DateTime.Now,
            Slug = "جلسه-اول-آموزش-mvc",
            Status = true,
            Title = "جلسه اول آموزش MVC",
            User = user,
            Course = course2
        }); context.Videos.AddOrUpdate(new Video()
        {
            Address = "/Videos/Admin/MVC/Vid01.mp4",
            Description = "در جلسه اول با این قسما ها آشنا می شویم. مدیریت،کاربران، و دیگر بخش ها",
            Keywords = "کلیدواژه,MVC,آموزش MVC",
            Picture = "/images/dummy/products/product-6.jpg",
            SentDate = DateTime.Now,
            Slug = "جلسه-اول-آموزش-mvc",
            Status = true,
            Title = "جلسه اول آموزش MVC",
            User = user,
            Course = course1
        }); context.Videos.AddOrUpdate(new Video()
        {
            Address = "/Videos/Admin/MVC/Vid01.mp4",
            Description = "در جلسه اول با این قسما ها آشنا می شویم. مدیریت،کاربران، و دیگر بخش ها",
            Keywords = "کلیدواژه,MVC,آموزش MVC",
            Picture = "/images/dummy/products/product-6.jpg",
            SentDate = DateTime.Now,
            Slug = "جلسه-اول-آموزش-mvc",
            Status = true,
            Title = "جلسه اول آموزش MVC",
            User = user,
            Course = course2
        });
        context.SaveChanges();
        #endregion
```

please let me know what is my mistake in this codes. thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity Framework (EF) does not necessarily load all related objects when the object that references them is itself loaded. You can set the Context (which in your case you have named db) ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled property according to whether you always want those tables to be read and loaded into instances of this class immediately as soon as you read it from it's table, or to wait until those are themselves access through a navigation method.

To explicitly load an object such as User or Course, you can call their 'Load' method. This msdn entry provides some helpful information for this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896249(v=vs.100).aspx

Please let me know whether this helps. Good luck.
James Hurst